# exim4-base removal

Tags: debian, exim

Why does Debian Buster ship with the `exim4-base` package installed by default? Can I remove it from my system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove it. Note that will also remove `exim4-daemon-light` or `exim4-daemon-light` if you still have them, that's ok.

About your other question: a working system needs a way to deliver mail, at least locally, that's why Debian decided to ship Exim4 (I install ssmtp, which is arguably the simplest way to have that functionality, but postfix is another alternative).

Comment: Strictly speaking, local mail delivery only needs an MDA, not a full-blown MTA, but your explanation is accurate enough ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Debian ships with multiple SMTP daemons and you can choose to use any of then. Yes, it's safe to delete exim4-base.